# CC list is not working while sending email

Tags: python

I have the following code which sends email,the issue is the `CC` option doesn't seem to be working meaning people in the `CC` group are not receiving email,as a test I changed the group to `To` list it works,so any guidance on how to fix this?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib

def sendEmail2(type,data):
    email ='username@company.com'
    body = '''%s''' % (data)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    sender = 'techci@company.com'
    receivers = []
    cc = ['team-tech-integrators@group.company.com']
    REPLY_TO_ADDRESS = 'team-tech-integrators@group.company.com'
    if type =='OPERATIONfailure':
        b = '\U0001F6A8'
        receivers.append(email)
        msg['Subject'] = '%s AUTO OPERATION FAILED FOR GERRIT  :PLEASE TAKE IMMEDIATE ACTION!!!'%(b.decode('unicode-escape'))
    elif type == 'git_push_success':
        b = '\U0001F600'
        receivers = ['team-tech-integrators@group.company.com']
        msg['Subject'] = '%s AUTO OPERATION SUCCESS FOR !!!'%(b.decode('unicode-escape'))
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(receivers)
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(cc)
    msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    try:
        mail = smtplib.SMTP('relay.company.com', 25)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
        msg.add_header('reply-to', REPLY_TO_ADDRESS)
        mail.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print "Problem sending email"

def main():
    data = "test"
    sendEmail2("OPERATIONfailure",data)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you printed `msg.as_string()` to see the actual MIME content that's being built? Have you tried joining `Cc` on `', '` instead of `','` (adding a trailing space, the way your `To` field has it)?